# Traverse directory and zip certain subdirectories in place

Tags: bash, zip, subdirectory

How can I bulk-zip folders in subdirectories without including the parent folder in the zip archives? I have a folder structure like this:

```
folder01
    folder02
        file01
        file02
```

When I run:

```
find . -type d -name "folder02" -exec zip -r '{}'.zip '{}' \;
```

I get "folder02.zip" which always extracts its contents into a parent folder "folder01". How can I prevent this? For me it creates useless parent folder structures when extracting these archives anywhere else.

Comment: Try replacing `\;` by `+`

Comment: This creates a single ZIP file for all folders, not separate ZIP files for each folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some simple bash:

```
find . -type d -name "folder02" -exec bash -c 'cd "$(dirname "{}")"; zip -r "$(basename "{}")".zip "$(basename "{}")"' \;
```

Comment: Thanks! Close to perfect. It answers my question. One more question though: When I run zip with the -m option (move into zip and delete), it basically works, but spits out errors, that it cannot delete those items, which already seem to be deleted. Is there any queueing in the execution of the bash commands that has to be considered?

Comment: This fails if you have directories with names containing `"`.  Try this instead: `find . -type d -name "folder02" -execdir bash -c 'zip -r "$(basename "$1")".zip "$(basename "$1")"' sh {} \;`

Comment: Oh... Didn't know about `execdir`. In my earlier attempt (replace `\;` by `+`), I was trying something similar...